# Codeigniter removed index.php works locally but not on aws ELB

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, codeigniter-3

i have a codeigniter application in docker.

Locally: localhost/Login **OK**

AWS ELB: www.mywebsite.com/Login **KO**

AWS ELB: www.mywebsite.com/index.php/Login **OK**

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1-apache

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y git-core cron \
  libjpeg-dev libmcrypt-dev libpng-dev libpq-dev \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
  && docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-png-dir=/usr --with-jpeg-dir=/usr \
  && docker-php-ext-install gd mcrypt mysqli opcache pdo pdo_mysql zip



RUN { \
    echo 'opcache.memory_consumption=128'; \
    echo 'opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8'; \
    echo 'opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000'; \
    echo 'opcache.revalidate_freq=2'; \
    echo 'opcache.fast_shutdown=1'; \
    echo 'opcache.enable_cli=1'; \
  } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-ci-opcache.ini

RUN { \
    echo 'log_errors=on'; \
    echo 'display_errors=off'; \
    echo 'upload_max_filesize=32M'; \
    echo 'post_max_size=32M'; \
    echo 'memory_limit=128M'; \
    echo 'date.timezone="UTC"'; \
  } > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/docker-ci-php.ini

RUN { \
    echo '<FilesMatch "^\.">'; \
    echo '    Order allow,deny'; \
    echo '    Deny from all'; \
    echo '</FilesMatch>'; \
    echo '<DirectoryMatch "^\.|\/\.">'; \
    echo '    Order allow,deny'; \
    echo '    Deny from all'; \
    echo '</DirectoryMatch>'; \
  } > /etc/apache2/conf-available/docker-ci-php.conf

RUN a2enconf docker-ci-php

RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY . /var/www/html

EXPOSE 80
```

This works well locally, but when deploy this app on aws ELB require index.php on url.

config.php

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].'/';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'AUTO';
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable Rewrite Engine

If you are using Ubuntu then use below command

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`  Enable .htaccess